# HexBinaryValue.FromString OPENXML

Tags: openxml

Hi What paratemeter I need to pass to this function.
It is taking 00c0c0c0 format. I am not sure how to convert #00ccff into that format?
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

0000ccff, or even just 00ccff

Comment: This is correct but I think I scrwed up my code.
Thanks for the reply.